# Attribute filtering by comparing cause errors

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Model:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'things'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('types_of_things.id'))

class TypeOfThing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'types_of_things'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    number = db.Column(db.Integer)
    things = db.relationship('Thing', backref='type', lazy='dynamic')
```

Try:

```
Thing.query.join(TypeOfThing).filter_by(Thing.type.number<=1).first()
```

cause:

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor
>   'Comparator' object associated with Thing.type has an attribute
>   'number'

Try:

```
Thing.query.join(TypeOfThing).filter_by(number<=1).first()
```

Cause:

> NameError: name 'number' is not defined

Comment: The reason you can't use `number<=1` in `filter_by` is that it's typically looking for keyword arguments with the `=` sign, not comparisons. You can use `TypeOfThing.number` to pass the comparison as a positional argument. (`number` may not be used on its own because it is not defined.)

Comment: @2Cubed I can't use number because it's not defined, but why `Thing.type.number` comparison cause error? Furthermore, it seems like I might do this: `Thing.query.join(TypeOfThing).filter_by(assembled=1)` (without comparing) - `assembled` is still not defined. I'll accept your answer with a bit explanation.

Comment: @2Cubed, oh, i thought `filter_by` is an alias for `filter` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I need do it so:

```
Thing.query.join(TypeOfThing).filter(TypeOfThing.number<=1).first()
```